# How to loop json and parse the value

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

This is my php code **[EDITED]**:

```
$redis_data =  file_get_contents("http://example.org/data/data.txt");
```

That code returns the following json data:

```
{"Phone":"08XXXXX","StartTime":"121212","Customer":"Customer A","time":1407921302}
{"Phone":"08XXXXX0","StartTime":"111111","Customer":"Customer B","time":1407921302
{"Phone":"08XXXXX","StartTime":"131313","Customer":"Customer C","time":1407921302}
```

This is my code to looping parse the value:

```
$redis_data =  file_get_contents("http://example.org/data/data.txt");
$redis_data = json_decode($redis_data, true);

foreach ($redis_data as $data) {
    echo $data['Phone'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

But I got this errors:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution

```
$redis_data =  explode( chr(10), file_get_contents("http://example.com/tes_redis/data.txt"));

foreach ($redis_data as $data) { 
    var_dump(json_decode($data));
     $data = json_decode($data);
     echo $data->Phone;
     echo $data->StartTime;
     echo $data->Customer;
     //echo $data->ANumber;
     //echo $data->BNumber;
}
```

you need to export data first.

Comment: You would be better off outputting the json on the remote page properly.

Answer (score 3):

The data you trying to get is not well formatted json

```
[{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName": "Jones"}]
```

This is the json syntax.
 and you are getting data in following format.

`{"ANumber":"08122378673","BNumber":"500046","StartTime":"08122014102113","EndTime":"08122014104126","TrunkA":"S1JK2SBD1S","TrunkB":"N7JK2GSM1B","Customer":"PT.BNI","time":1407921302}
{"ANumber":"081351607600","BNumber":"14000","StartTime":"08122014102406","EndTime":"08122014103738","TrunkA":"S1JK2SSB1S","TrunkB":"EPJK2MNR0","Customer":"Bank Mandiri (CC_IB_Jasnita)","time":1407921302}`

You may need to reformat your data string

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to loop JSON - not PHP. You need to run `json_decode` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)) on the your `$redis_data` variable before attempting to loop it.

```
$redis_data = json_decode($redis_data, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode the json before you can loop through it.

```
$redis_data =  json_decode(file_get_contents("http://example.com/tes_files/data.txt"), true);

foreach ($redis_data as $data) {
   echo $data['phone'];
}
```

Comment: Try doing `foreach ($redis_data[0] as $data) {`

Comment: I believe the problem is malformed JSON. Did you code the output of the JSON on the remote page?

Answer (score 0):

first you have to convert json to array using **json_decode** function it will give array and after that you can loop

```
  `
     $jsonString =
    '[{"Phone":"08XXXXX","StartTime":"121212","Customer":"Customer A","time":1407921302},
    {"Phone":"08XXXXX0","StartTime":"111111","Customer":"Customer B","time":1407921302},
    {"Phone":"08XXXXX","StartTime":"131313","Customer":"Customer C","time":1407921302} ]';
    $array=json_decode($jsonString);

    foreach ($arrayOfEmails as $data) {
       echo $data->Phone."<br>";
    }
```

`